# Looping through Excel Cells and writing them to Word

Tags: vba, excel, loops, ms-word

I am using a Macro in Excel to loop through cells and write the data into a Template in Word.  Everything worked completely fine until I wanted to add more cells to grab data from. Everything still works fine except once the variable I have name "j" gets to the value of 25, I get an error saying "Run-time error '5941': The requested member of the collection does not exist."

I've played around with using different rows and columns and every combination works. It is only when the "`j`" reaches 25 does the error occur. It is failing when it reaches the `wrd.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(j)`... line.

```
Sub Label_ExcelToWord_Single()
    'Variable that stores file path for
    'word template
    Dim strpath As String
    strpath = Cells(28, 8)

    'opens Microsoft Word to edit template
    Call OpenWord

    Set wrd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    wrd.Visible = True
    wrd.Activate

    wrd.ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=False
    wrd.Documents.Open strpath

    'Variables used for loop data manipulation
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    k = 1
    j = 1

    'Primary loop responsible for exporting Excel
    'data to word template
    For Col = 1 To 3
        For Row = 3 To 32
            wrd.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(j).Cells(((Row - 3) Mod 7) + k).Range.Text = Cells(Row, Col) & vbCrLf & Cells(Row, Col)
            If k = 7 Then
                k = 0
                j = j + 2
            End If
            If Col = 3 Then
                If Row = 32 Then
                    'When we reach the last cell containing data exit routine
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
            k = k + 1
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How many rows does Table(1) have? If Table(1) has 24 rows, then you might get such an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the table might not have enough rows.  If so, a brute-force way is to add rows as you need them:

```
...
For Col = 1 To 3
    For Row = 3 To 32
        ' vvv new lines vvv
        Do While wrd.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count < j
            wrd.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Add
        Loop
        ' ^^^ new lines ^^^
        ...
```

I also recommend renaming `j`, `k`, `Row`, and `Col` to more descriptive names.  You have Excel row/column indices and Word-table row/column indices, and it's easy to get them confused unless the names are clear.

(Note: Yes, the above code is slow, clunky, unoptimized, yadda yadda.  Hopefully it will help the OP. :) )

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a lot easier to use DocVariables in Word and push your data from Excel cells into the DocVariables.  The end game is about the same, but I think the code is a lot easier to setup and maintain.

```
Sub PushToWord()

Dim objWord As New Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim bkmk As Word.Bookmark
sWdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , , , False)
Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open(sWdFileName)
'On Error Resume Next

objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("FirstName").Value = Range("FirstName").Value
objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("LastName").Value = Range("LastName").Value
objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("AnotherVariable").Value = Range("AnotherVariable").Value

objWord.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update

'On Error Resume Next
objWord.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Set a reference ot the MS Word Object Library.